# How can i re-display a DataGridView with programmatically changed cell values

Tags: .net, winforms

Using a DataGridView with DataSource=null, how can i re-display the grid with programmatically changed cell values.  I have tried refresh & Update, but the display doesn't change...I have verified that the new value are in the cells.

```
                private void dataGridView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // The mouse locations are relative to the screen, so they must be 
        // converted to client coordinates.
        Point myClientPoint = dataGridView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        // Get the row index of the item the mouse is over. 
        m_TargetHTI = dataGridView1.HitTest(myClientPoint.X, myClientPoint.Y);
        DataGridViewCell myTargetCell = dataGridView1[m_TargetHTI.ColumnIndex, m_TargetHTI.RowIndex];

        if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move)
        {
            //save the source/target cell's original values
            AddCellHistory(m_DragCell);
            AddCellHistory(myTargetCell);
            //
            //move source to target
            dataGridView1.Rows[m_TargetHTI.ColumnIndex].Cells[m_TargetHTI.RowIndex].Value = m_DragCell.Value;
            //
            //clear source cell
            dataGridView1.Rows[m_SourceHTI.ColumnIndex].Cells[m_SourceHTI.RowIndex].Value = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code.  There's no way we can know what's happening without seeing how you're doing things.

Comment: Are you updating from within a loop?...a different form?  Some details and code would be good.

Comment: I added some code...no loops, same form...

Comment: roryap...you were right there was no way to figure this how without seeing the code...I had some row & column indexes mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

You should invoke the Invalidate method on the datagrid, like this:

```
dataGridView1.Invalidate();
```

Comment: @Dleh, this provide an answer to the question.  His question is clear and does not need an explanation.